# How to check if a list contains items with a Converter?

Tags: c#

I want check if a `Collection` of a specific `Controller` have items, and then perform some task on the button like `IsEnabled`, what I did is:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContactController.MyList, Converter={x:Static HaveItemsConverter}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I'm not pretty sure how can I convert a `List<T>` to the controller, pseudo code:

```
 public class HaveItemsConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var list = value as List<T>

       if(list.Count > 0)
         return true;

       return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("IsNullConverter can only be used OneWay.");
    }
}
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IList coll = (IList)value;

        if (coll.Count > 0)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```